# Retrieving a piece of text form a text field in Mysql DB until a special character is found

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Am wondering whether and how i can retrieve a portion of text data from the text field in MSQL DB. What SQL function can i use in my query statement.

Eg.I have a text field containing data that looks like below;

(firstname1,lastname1,23,,district1,state1,province1),(firstname2,lastname2,23,,district2,state2,province2),
(firstname3,lastname3,23,,district3,state3,province3),...etc

how would i select for example a piece of data starting from

"lastname1" to ")" the bracket closing the first set.

am trying to figure out how i can do this but still failing.
The thing is i don't want to retrieve all the data in the text field...so am wondering whether the MySQL query statements can help...

though the regular expressions would be of great use in this case as i think, but i don't know how to structure them, am a new Bi...please help me at-least on this case.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This does seem like a good place to use an regex. Why not try looking at this if you have a problem building regular expressions 
http://txt2re.com/ 
That is a regular expression generator that should help build the regular expression to extract the data you need.

Comment: Thanks Tony let me try it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it directly in MYSQL. Something like this would work:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( YOUR_COLUMN, INSTR( YOUR_COLUMN,  'START_CHAR_GOES_HERE' ) , INSTR( YOUR_COLUMN,  'END_CHAR_GOES_HERE' ) - INSTR( YOUR_COLUMN,  'START_CHAR_GOES_HERE' ) ) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

reference: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Comment: For now, Alexey, u nailed it...it worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Comment: am wondering how to make this statement keep returning portions of data that match the condition such that it does something like looping through the entire text and picking the text starting from the "lastname1" to ")" for this case.                                        ie if there were more than one occurrences of the possible strings starting with "lastname1"...     thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 1):

use `locate()`, `substr()` and `char_length()` in mysql.

Also read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).

Comment: thanks Chris, but for char_length() the length of the string portion to retrieve will be anonymous,......for substr() and locate(), i think i could use the locate() to locate the start position but the end position would hard to get unless if i would identify a character eg ")" to indicate the end position...

Comment: it is the first occurance of the closing parenthesis that occurs *after* the position of lastname1. locate() can take that position as an offset - where to start looking. well, unless your data itself can contain closing parenthesis. in that case, i feel sorry for you :)

Comment: I have plans of saving the data in the format as shown above, with the parenthesis where each data in the parenthesis pairs as separated by commas would fall under a particular field. but this time it has been parked together to occupy on field in the database....the main problem is that the data portions in the parenthesis pairs will be changing that's why i could not create specific fields for each portion in the db.please Chris help me if u have a better idea on this.thanks.